# Creating and Selecting from a Named Window

Tags: java, esper

I have Esper running locally and I am feeding in (via XML) a handful of EPL statements -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Statements>
    <Statement>
        create window OrderEventWindow.win:keepall() as select * from OrderEvent
    </Statement>
    <Statement>
        @Name("OrderEventsFromWindow")
        @Description("Outputs any Order events from the window")
        select * from OrderEventWindow
    </Statement>
    <Statement>
        @Name("OrderEventsFromDirect")
        @Description("Outputs any Order events from the feed")
        select * from OrderEvent
    </Statement>
</Statements>
```

This appears to go in fine without any errors. However, the issue now is that it appears as though the above statement called "OrderEventsFromWindow" is not running as I see no results being output (despite events of type OrderEvent coming in).

What is strange is that the other statement "OrderEventsFromDirect" is working as expected.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong that would explain why my first statement is not showing any output?

*Note all statements in my XML are being fed in on application start up as follows:

```
    for (String stmt : statements) {
        EPStatement statement = admin.createEPL(stmt);
        statement.addListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named windows start empty and the "create window OrderEventWindow.win:keepall() as OrderEvent" just defines the type of the rows in the named window, in your case they are the same row type as OrderEvent.
You'd want to insert all order events into the named window using "insert into OrderEventWindow select * from OrderEvent" if that is what you want to insert.

Comment: Thanks, I have added in:  
`<Statement>insert into OrderEventWindow select * from OrderEvent</Statement>`  

This appears to have done the trick, my window is now being populated as expected and I can select from it without any issues.

However, I noticed that after adding this in I receive some additional output - possibly from the select * from OrderEvent in the insert statement? Is there anyway to filter this out (Creates unnecessary noise).